# Random DataFrame sample with at least 1 unique value of a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to randomly sample my Dataframe but in the sample there should be at least 1 unique value of a specific column:

The dataset has a column: "Month" which is a numeric value from 1 to 12; I'd like to have at least one row for each month in my random sample.

This is what I'm using to sample:

```py
df = df.sample(frac=0.2, replace=True, random_state=1)
```

UPDATE:

Applying Quang Hoang answer seems working:
the initial `df.count()` gives me **864806** rows, after applying the function it goes to **172956** and if I do `df['month'].unique()` I get:

```
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12])
```

Is there a pandas builtin method to do the same?

Comment: Generally, with your dat size, when you do random sampling, you have to be really unlucky to miss some of the unique values.

Comment: Yes but I cannot use that as an excuse xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe:

```
def sample(chunk, rate=0.2):
    n = max(int(len(chunk)*rate), 1)

    return chunk.sample(n=n, replace=True, random_state=1)

df.groupby('month', group_keys=False).apply(sample)
```

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted you answer, I'm updating my question to include the results using your function. Is there a builtin function by pandas to do the same?

Comment: Oh can you modify your function to accept more then 1 column? Like suppose I have another feature 'weekday' and I want my sample to contain at least 1 row for each month and at least 1 row for day of the week (0 to 6 where 0 is Monday and 6 is Sunday)

Comment: I think I figure it out just adding: `df = df.groupby(['MONTHOFSERVICE','WEEKDAY'], group_keys=False).apply(sample)`

Comment: Replace `'month'` inside groupby by `['col1', 'col2',...]`.

Comment: @QuangHoang is there a way to make `random_state` variable so that I can put the `sample` function in a loop?